# Implement RTL layout from ios 8 to later

Tags: ios, ios8, uikit

> Can you please help me to implement RTL layout for arabic language in
>   ios 8.
>   [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html)
>
> already go through this link,
>
> I just worried this line "UIKit controls
>   appear flipped when the app links against iOS 9 and later.", Question
>   is how to implement RTL layout like UI control's for tableview,
>   splitviewcontroller, segmented controls, progress indicators, and
>   outline views etc in ios 8. What I have to make different-2 layout or
>   using base international do itself in ios 8.

Answer (score 0):

My most honest answer would be to not be so worried about iOS 8... just follow the guide as much as you can in terms of using Auto Layout and localization API–anything that's not handled by you, such as UIKit controls, should not be interfered with as they will 'just work' for anyone running iOS 9 and above.